# Create Calendar view using list definition with visual 2010 (sharepoint 2010)

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, calendar, list-definition, view

I'm a newer in sharepoint 2010 .I want to create calendar view for my list definition using list definition. I think i need to do something in schema.xml file, but i can't find any document talk about this. What can i do now ? please help me .

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like

```
<View BaseViewID="2" DisplayName="Team Calendar" Type="CALENDAR" WebPartZoneID="Main" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/events.png" Url="calendar.aspx" RecurrenceRowset="TRUE" DefaultView="TRUE" ShowHeaderUI="TRUE" MobileUrl="_layouts/15/mobile/viewdaily.aspx"/>
```

More on the view definition http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms430995.aspx